# How to use pdfkit to render image in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pdf, pdfkit

Can anyone step-by-step or with example explain how to install and use `pdfkit` in rails to render images present in html.?

I have installed `pdfkit` along with `wkhtmltopdf-binary`. When i do

```
require 'pdfkit'
kit = PDFKit.new('http://google.com')
gpdf = kit.to_file('/home/blackat/Desktop/gpdf.pdf')
```

it will generate a pdf of google home page perfectly. So it is meant that `pdfkit` installed correctly in my system(correct me if it is wrong).

As mentioned in the [railcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/220-pdfkit) i did all the changes.

1. `gem 'pdfkit'` # in my Gemfile
2. `bundle install`
3. `require 'pdfkit'`  # in application.rb
4. `config.middleware.use "PDFKit::Middleware", :print_media_type => true` #in application.rb

to check weather it works or not i did some workaround in my controller
like this

```
html_data = render_to_string :layout => false
html_file_path = "demo.html"
pdf_file_path = "demo.pdf"
f = File.open(html_file_path, "w")
f.write(html_data)
f.close

kit = PDFKit.new(html_data,:page_size => 'Letter')
pdf_file = kit.to_file(pdf_file_path)
```

When i remove images from my html.erb template, a pdf will generate. If i specify any images in my erb template or if i include ".pdf" in browser execution hangs for lifetime.

Where i am doing wrong?
is there any blog/example to refer?

Does the 'wkhtmltopdf' installed correctly?

Please help me in this. i am trying this from 2 weeks.

I am using rails '3.2.11'
and ruby 1.9.3

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're generating the PDF from a local HTML file. Make sure you're using absolute paths so wkhtmltopdf can find your stylesheet and images. (open `demo.html` in your browser to see what's missing)

Comment: @Stefan i used simple inline css (i think this will not bomb). I will try with absolute path to images.

Comment: @Stefan i have changed my image path as like this `<%= image_tag("/images/myImage.png")%>` 
which renders image in my view. but when i convert it  using `render_to_string` it only returning `<img alt="MyImage"  src="/images/myImage.jpg" />` 

How can i tell to take absolute path when doing `render_to_string` ?

Comment: @Stefan if i append image tag with #{Rails.root} pdfkit hangs .

Comment: IIRC, you can use [`image_url`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-image_url) to compute the full URL, i.e `image_tag(image_url('file.png'))`. Here's how I would approach this: (1) generate a local HTML file `demo.html` (2) open the file in a browser and fix any errors (3) generate a PDF from this file using the command line tool: `wkhtmltopdf demo.html demo.pdf` (4) launch IRB and invoke PDFKit manually (5) insert that code in your controller.

Comment: @Stefan do i need to configure assets? i am getting `undefined method image_url' for #<#<Class:0xfaec6f8>:0xfdf767c>` error.

Comment: @Stefan i mean do i need to configure `application.helper` (http://stick.gk2.sk/2009/12/image_url-function-in-ruby-on-rails/)

Comment: Not sure, it works out of the box on my system.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving absolute path of image file in your view like:

`%img{src: "file://#{Rails.root}/public/imagesmyImage.png"}`

Comment: in the dev env, the images will be loaded from assets folder where as in the prod env, the images will be loaded from public. How do we handle this case?